# Put aspx file in background-image like im src

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, image, background-image

My asp.net application contains img with another aspx file in src attribute,
with a picture,

```
<img src="/picture.aspx?Param=3" alt="picture"/>
```

I have to change the img to div with backgroung-image.

```
<div style="background-image:url('/picture.aspx?Param=3')" />
```

Any way to do it?
Thanks!

Comment: Nope, there's no way to use ASP files as CSS backgrounds.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would handle this is creating a method that returns a base64 png in a similar manner as you return an image resource from picture.aspx?param=3.

```
Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath(@"image_file.png")));
```

Then you can assign it to the background:

```
<div style='background-image: url(data:image/png;base64," + base64String + ")'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Html:**

```
<div id="dv" />
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#dv').load('picture.aspx?Param=3');
```